# Нужно вставить формулу в цикл.(Python)

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

Ниже прилагаю задание и код, который я думал заработает, но выдает ошибку. Я только недавно начал изучать питон, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: код]
[image: задание]

Comment: а теперь текстом

Comment: И где код-то? Прилагайте.

Comment: В чем заключается проблема? Какие ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выше указали, для получения элемента из списка нужно использовать `h[i]`.

В добавок к этому скорее всего вы получаете ошибку: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Ошибка связана с логикой работы вашей программы: на последней итерации цикла индекс j выходит за пределы массива:

Возможное исправление ошибок:

```python
n = int(input())
h = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]
max_ = 0
for i in range(n - 1):
    j = i + 1
    x = i - j + h[j] - h[i]
    max_ += x
print(max_)
```